# IDA search for multiple instructions

Tags: regex, assembly, search, ida

I've been having some issues getting IDA's text search to cooperate. I want to use a regex to find something along the lines of:

```
mov eax, *
retn
```

but for some reason ida keeps returning 0 results. i can find the mov instruction just fine if i use `mov *eax, .`, but when i try to search for both instructions at once (eg: `mov *eax, .*\nretn`) it doesnt seem to be able to match. im assuming its some issue with the newline but ive tried every solution i can think of (`\n` `\R` `(?m)` `(*ANY)` `...` etc) without any progress.

[heres the guide ive been using](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/578.shtml) and this is the field im searching:

```
sub_401000      sub_401000 proc near                    ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0044B6C0↓o
sub_401000      mov     eax, offset off_44B660
sub_401000+5    retn
sub_401000+5    sub_401000 endp
```

im aware that binary search would accomplish multiline searching but it needs absolute values, whereas i just want to match the instruction and have the registers and values be wildcard. anyone know a solution?

Comment: If it's a regex, ` *` matches any number of spaces.  Perhaps you want `.*` to match any number of any character?  Many regex search things are line-oriented and only try to match single lines against the regex; IDK if you'll be able to use a pattern that includes a newline.  (I don't use IDA so I'm not going to try to read the docs and find out.)

Comment: nope `.*` doesn't work either :/. Being single line would make sense though

Comment: Try `mov *eax, .*\r?\nretn` or `mov *eax, .*[\r\n]+retn` If you also have to match the part before it, then `mov *eax, .*\r?\n.* retn` See https://regex101.com/r/2WuEeW/1

Comment: Or find both lines from the start of the string with multiline `^\S+\p{Z}+\bmov\p{Z}+eax,.*\R\S+\p{Z}+retn\b` https://regex101.com/r/T1lkOr/1

Comment: nope none of those seemed to work. i think Peter Cordes was right and it only searches one line at a time

Answer (score 2):

Like Peter Cordes said, it seems that ida's text search only covers one line at a time. Luckily IDA has python scripting! Here's what solved my problem. This script looks through the target process for a POP POP RET pattern

```py
from idaapi import *
from idautils import *
from idc import *

def find_test():
    base = idaapi.get_imagebase()
    while True:
        res = FindBinary(base, SEARCH_NEXT|SEARCH_DOWN, "C3")
        if res==BADADDR: break
        if 0b01011 == get_byte(res-1) >> 3 and 0b01011 == get_byte(res-2) >> 3: 
            print "{0:X}".format(res)
        base=res+1
```